# Asynchronous messaging with Android Parse push Notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, message-queue

I wanted to send Asynchronous messaging with Parse,

When i push a notification,client devices may not be online but i wish them receive all notifications after being online.
but when i pushed 2 notification  client just received 1 notification(The last one).

Is there any queue semantic with Android Parse push notification?

Comment: Have you set expiration date for the notifications?

Comment: may be the id of notification is same

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ thank ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ but i didn't set any expiration date maybe it has  a default ! but it didn't take much after receiving.

Comment: @TonyStark thanks but they have different id.

Comment: I didnt see mention of default expiration in anywhere...try clearing the expiration using `clearExpiration()`

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ where can i call this method?

Comment: You have to invoke using the `ParsePush` object, before sending the notification

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ I test clearExpiration() but nothing changed!